# How do I read random cells in C# and print them out in a textbox?

Tags: c#, excel, xls, xlsx

It has soon been 12h of trying this and I can't get it to work. I have read all the threads I can find and nothing helps. I have tried to fiddle around with Excel Wrapper as well but it doesn't work. **I'm new to C# and I'm trying to do a bullshit generator.** What I am trying to  do is reading a bunch of words from A1-A5, B1-B5 and C1-C5 in an .xlsx-file and putting them together in a textbox (I'm using Visual Studio) when clicking a button.

If anyone reads this and could give me a hint it would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post some of your code and any errors you have. We love to help you... but we need to know where you are to help and not do it for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should pull the info from the xls doc to a collection (array, list, etc...)
The code for this should be easy to find online.

You are also going to need a random number generator:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
```

Then you are going to have the button click event select 2 random numbers, one for row and one for column, from your collection (2D array in this case):

```
int row_max = stuff[][].GetLength(0); 
int col_max = stuff[][].GetLength(1); 
int row = rnd.Next(0, row_max-1)
int col = rnd.Next(0, col_max-1); //between 0 and the number of columns
textbox1.text = textbox1.text + stuff[row][col].ToString();
```

This is indicative only, but all the parts of this can be easily googled.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot! Will keep going. Thanks again!